# syncing scrollbars using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.scroll').bind('scroll', scrollBarSync);
        });

        function scrollBarSync(event) {
            console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));

            $('.scroll').unbind('scroll');

            $.each($('.scroll'), function(index, value) {
                var left = $(value).scrollLeft();

                if ($(event.target).attr('id') != $(value).attr('id') &&
                        left != $(event.target).scrollLeft()) {

                    $(value).scrollLeft($(event.target).scrollLeft())
                }
            });

            $('.scroll').bind('scroll', scrollBarSync);

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

And the following html:

```
        <style>
    .hidden {
        display:none;
    }
    .scroll {
        overflow: scroll;
        width:200px;
    }
    td {
        width:45px !important;
        height:47px;
    }
    table {
        width:100% !important;
    }
    </style>

<div id="scroll_table_1" class="scroll"> 
        <table> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div> 
    <br /> 
    <div id="scroll_table_2" class="scroll"> 
        <table> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div> 
    <br /> 
    <div id="scroll_table_3" class="scroll"> 
        <table> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th class="hidden">text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                    <th>text</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td class="hidden">text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                    <td>text</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div> 
    <br />
```

Why exactly does every browser but chrome call the scrolling function more than once?  It's like the scrolling left happens after it's already back being bound by each element.  It's pretty confusing.

I've tried creating custom events and triggering them sequentially and it doesn't seem to matter.  I've been beating myself up over this for two days now, any ideas?

Chrome's output when scrolling the first scroll bar is scroll_table_1 while FF and IE is scroll_table_1, scroll_table_2, scroll_table_3, etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks patrick!  That works great in everything but IE7 and FF on Windows.  The scrollbar you're currently dragging has this weird back and forth effect in those browsers.  And doing console logging instead of running that scroll bar function once (which was what I was trying to do with unbinding and binding) it runs over itself over and over.  I think most of the newer browsers JS engines are better but apparently IE7 and FF choke.

Comment: That's strange. I don't get any sort of back and forth effect. It works very well for me in FF and IE7. Binding and unbinding is a fairly expensive operation as I understand it. I would think it would just slow it down. I'll update my answer with an `if()` statement you could try, but really, I don't think it would be necessary. Maybe there's some other issue causing the problems you described.